# Getting relative frequencies for a categorical variable (filtered on a count)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame of student test results, where the two columns that interest me are `country` and `result`, as in:

```
country    result
FR         Pass
FR         Fail
US         Pass
US         Pass
DK         Fail
DK         Fail
SE         Pass
...        ...
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the relative "Fail" frequency per country, descending (meaning - I want the students from that country that failed, as a percentage of all the students from that particular country), but only for countries that had over, let's say, 200 students take the test:

```
country    % fail    students
FR         0.056     997
US         0.051     855
DK         0.042     627
NL         0.032     511
```

I've seen colleagues at work do it with a very short SQL query, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it with pandas!

Comment: your input data are incomplete ... moreover what have you tried so far in Python? It's not a place where you have a free coffee...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groupby.agg. First I created a random dataset:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
countries = ["FR", "US", "DK", "SE", "NL"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"country": np.random.choice(countries, 1000), "result": np.random.choice(["Pass", "Fail"], 1000)})
```

It has 1000 rows with country and result columns. Then I used groupby to find the percentages.

```
gb = df.groupby("country")
gb['result'].agg(lambda x: len(x[x=="Fail"]) / len(x))[gb.size() > 195]
Out[100]: 
country
FR    0.472362
SE    0.520362
US    0.553299
Name: result, dtype: float64
```

The first part (`gb['result'].agg(lambda x: len(x[x=="Fail"]) / len(x))`) calculates the percentages and `[gb.size() > 195]` filters it so that it only shows the ones having more than 195 students.

For the exact match of your sample output, you can try something like this:

```
gb['result'].agg({"% fail": lambda x: len(x[x=="Fail"]) / len(x), "students": len})[gb.size() > 195].sort_values(by="% fail", ascending=False)
Out[119]: 
           % fail  students
country                    
US       0.553299       197
SE       0.520362       221
FR       0.472362       199
```